# When sending the data, it is not displayed useContext undefined

Tags: reactjs

When sending the data, it is not displayed useContext undefined ?
When sending the data, it is not displayed useContext undefined
When sending the data, it is not displayed useContext undefined
When sending the data, it is not displayed useContext undefined

**Card.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const UserContext = React.createContext();
export const TypeContext= React.createContext();

function Cards({item}) {

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={'islam'} >
        <TypeContext.Provider value={'Abdelradi'}>
                    <Card className='mr-3 rounded-tl-xl rounded-tr-xl my-2' key={item.id}>
                        <div className='h-[330px]'>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" className='rounded-tl-xl rounded-tr-xl h-[100%]' src={item.img} />
                        </div>

                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{ item.title }</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted text-[13px]">{ item.country}</Card.Subtitle>
                        <hr />
                        <div className='flex justify-between px-3'>
                            <p>CULTURAL <br /> RELAX</p>
                            <h1 className=' font-bold text-2xl text-slate-700'>${item.price}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <Card.Text className=' text-[14px] text-slate-500'>
                        {item.text }
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Link to={`/View/${item.id}`}>
                            <Button variant="primary " className='btns border-none rounded-full  text-[14px] px-10 text-white py-2 my-2  '>DETAILS</Button>
                        </Link>
                    </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
        </TypeContext.Provider>
        </UserContext.Provider>

    )
}

export default Cards
```

**Viwe.jsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import{ UserContext,TypeContext } from './Cards';

function View() {
    
    const Type = useContext(TypeContext);
    const user = useContext(UserContext);
    console.log({user},{Type});

    return (
            <div className='mt-5'>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col text-white">
                            <div className='devimgview'>
                            </div>
                            <h1>{user},{Type}</h1>
                            {/* <p>{overview}</p>
                            <p>{vote_average}</p> */}
                            <button className='btn btn-secondary'>back</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6 align-items-center d-flex btn-leftview">
                            {/* <button className='btn btn-danger'>Play</button>
                            <button className='btn btn-success'>List</button> */}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    )
}

export default View
```

**error**

> {user: undefined} {Type: undefined}

Comment: `View` is not a child of the context providers, so you can't access contexts' values from that component.

Answer (score 0):

You're initialized your contexts with no value

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();
export const TypeContext= React.createContext();
```

If you don't want the values to be `undefined`, either initialize `createContext` with a value

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext("islam");
export const TypeContext= React.createContext("Abdelradi");
```

or account for `undefined` in your component.

Comment: Here value     <UserContext.Provider value={'islam'} >

Comment: The type of `user` and `Type` will still be `string | undefined` if you don't pass a value to `createContext`

Comment: Watch this https://youtu.be/dbOg-DhtG1g